# how to make isRowSelectable checked and desable if it is not selectable in Mui DataTable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, material-ui, mui-datatable

I would like to desable some rows by default with checked & desabled when the row is not selactable
but what i got like row is desable perfectly but not along with checked
this condition will work based on the state property in array

condition:
if isDesabled : true, then we have to do make the above approach

i have constomised the table a lot according to my needs and i got lot as i expected but except the above senario

here is the my full code in one file

```
import React from "react";
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";

export function App() {
  const columns = [
    { name: "name", label: "Name", options: { filter: true } },
    { name: "title", label: "Title", options: { filter: true } },
    { name: "location", label: "Location", options: { filter: true } }
  ];

  const data = [
    {
      isSelected: true,
      name: "Jhon",
      title: "leader",
      location: "house",
      isDisabled: true
    },
    {
      isSelected: false,
      name: "don",
      title: "ruler",
      location: "on table",
      isDisabled: false
    },
    {
      isSelected: true,
      name: "brooke",
      title: "scalse",
      location: "on table",
      isDisabled: true
    },
    {
      isSelected: false,
      name: "great",
      title: "eariser",
      location: "paper",
      isDisabled: false
    },
    {
      isSelected: true,
      name: "simple",
      title: "protector",
      location: "round",
      isDisabled: true
    }
  ];

  const [stateData, setStateData] = React.useState(data);

  const handleRowClick = (rowData, { dataIndex }) => {
    // console.log(dataIndex);

    const updatedData = stateData.map((row, ind) =>
      ind === dataIndex && !row.isDisabled
        ? { ...row, isSelected: !row.isSelected }
        : row
    );
    setStateData(updatedData);
  };
  const checkboxHandler = (currentRowsExpanded) => {
    if (currentRowsExpanded.length > 1) {
      setStateData((prev) => prev.map((eg) => ({ ...eg, isSelected: true })));
    } else if (currentRowsExpanded.length === 1) {
      const { dataIndex } = currentRowsExpanded[0];
      setStateData((prev) =>
        prev.map((row, ind) =>
          ind === dataIndex && !row.isDisabled
            ? { ...row, isSelected: !row.isSelected }
            : row
        )
      );
    } else if (currentRowsExpanded.length === 0) {
      setStateData((prev) => prev.map((eg) => ({ ...eg, isSelected: false })));
    }
  };
  const getCheckedArray = stateData
    .map((row, index) => (row.isSelected && !row.isDisabled ? index : null))
    .filter((index) => index !== null);

  const options = {
    search: false,
    download: false,
    print: false,
    filter: false,
    filterType: "dropdown",
    selectableRowsHeader: true,
    customToolbarSelect: () => null,
    customToolbar: () => {},
    isRowSelectable: (dataIndex) => !stateData[dataIndex].isDisabled,
    onRowClick: handleRowClick,
    rowsSelected: getCheckedArray,
    onRowSelectionChange: checkboxHandler
  };

  return (
    <MUIDataTable
      title={"ACME Employee list"}
      data={stateData}
      columns={columns}
      options={options}
    />
  );
}
```

**current outcome**

row is desable(with gray shade) but not along with checked

**expected outcome**
row has to checked and desabled if isDesable is true in array

here is my working sandcodebox

https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-glade-2bzlg7?file

please help me out from this issue

thanks advance!!